# How to delete individual elements from textview on Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am doing this project, can anyone help me to delete individual elements from the text view?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xylN3.png)

here's i implemented the 'button'  to insert and 'button2' to delete, and here's the code down bellow

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // To hold all data in different mode : Portrait and landscape
    private final String text_context = "TX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: in");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textView));

        textView.setText(""); // make it no text at runtime, but text at view
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); // make it scrolling
        editText.setText("");

        final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String result = editText.getText().toString();
                result += "\n";
                textView.append(result);
                editText.setText(""); // text on EDITTEXT will disappear as soon as we click the button
            }
        };

        final View.OnClickListener onClickListener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        };

        if(editText != null)
            button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:out");
    }
}
```

Please help me TO IMPLEMENT DELETE ACTION VIA BUTTON2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your onclick listeners are generically listening for clicks on any view.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle button events
    }
});


button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle button2 events
    }
});
```

Or better yet implement View.OnClickListener() on your activity

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();
String regex = "\\b" + input + "\\b";
String tvText = textView.getText().toString();
tvText = tvText.replaceAll(regex, "");
textView.setText(tvText);
```

Put this code in

```
    final View.OnClickListener onClickListener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             //code goes here
        }
    };

    if(editText != null)
        // add this onclick to your button2
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener1);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:out");
}
```